# What are the implications of using lightweight transactions?

Tags: transactions, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

In particular I was looking at [this page](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/latest/cassandra/dml/dmlLtwtTransactions.html) where it says:

> If lightweight transactions are used to write to a row within a partition, only lightweight transactions for both read and write operations should be used.

I'm confused as to what using LWTs for read operations looks like. Specifically how this relates to per-query consistency (and serialConsistency) levels.

The [description](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/latest/cassandra/dml/dmlConfigConsistency.html) for `SERIAL` read consistency raises further questions:

> Allows reading the current (and possibly uncommitted) state of data without proposing a new addition or update.

That suggests that using `SERIAL` for reads is not "using a LWT".

But then

- How does Cassandra know to check for in-progress transactions when you do a read?
- What is the new update that is proposed while you're trying to read, and how does this affect the read?
- How would that work if the consistency you're reading at (say `ONE` for example) is less than the serialConsistency used for writing?
- Once you use a LWT on a table (or row?, or column?), are all non-`SERIAL` reads forced to take the penalty of participating in quorums and the transaction algorithm?
- Does the requirement actually apply to the whole row, or just the columns involved in the conditional statement?

If I ignore this advice and make both serial and non-serial reads/writes. In what way to the LWTs fail?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28836083/476716

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How does Cassandra know to check for in-progress transactions when you
>   do a read?

This is exactly what the `SERIAL` consistency level indicates. It makes sure that a query will only return results after all pending transactions have been fully executed.

> What is the new update that is proposed while you're trying to read,
>   and how does this affect the read?

I think what the doc is trying to say is that the read will be handled just like a LWT - just without make any updates on it's own.

> How would that work if the consistency you're reading at (say ONE for example) is less than the serialConsistency used for writing?

Reads using `SERIAL` will always imply `QUORUM` as consistency level. Reading with `ONE` will not provide you any guarantees provided by `SERIAL` and you can end up reading stalled data.

> Once you use a LWT on a table (or row?, or column?), are all non-SERIAL reads forced to take the penalty of participating in quorums and the transaction algorithm?

No. You can use non-SERIAL consistency levels for your queries and have them executed with the exact same performance characteristics as any other non-serial queries.

> Does the requirement actually apply to the whole row, or just the columns involved in the conditional statement?

No, I think you should be fine as long as you use different columns for serial reads/writes (including conditions) and regular reads/writes.

> If I ignore this advice and make both serial and non-serial reads/writes. In what way to the LWTs fail?

If you execute regular writes, not being executed as part of a LWT, those writes will be applied at any time, without interfering at all with the consensus process of LWTs. As a consequence, regular writes can in theory change a value that is part of a LWT condition at a time between evaluating the condition and applying the update, which is a potential cause for inconsistencies you wanted to avoid using LWTs.

Comment: LWTs will always be executed in context of a partition key.

Comment: "Reads using SERIAL will always imply QUORUM as consistency level." Are you sure? Maybe it depends on the driver. From the Java datastax ConsistencyLevel#isSerial source code: https://www.insight.io/github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/3.x/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/ConsistencyLevel.java, "Whether or not this consistency level is serial, that is, applies only to the "paxos" phase of a lightweight transaction".